# Laravel pluck fields from relations

Tags: php, laravel, laravelcollective, laravel-collection

I have a Seller object which has a related User. I need to fill a select from LaravelCollective so I need to make something like this:

```
{!! Form::selectGroup('seller_id', 'Seller', Seller::with('user')->pluck('user.first_name', 'id')->toArray(), null) !!}
```

The problem is that I cannot take fields from relationships (user.first_name).

How can I do it?

**UPDATE**

I want to avoid doing this...

```
<?php 
    $sellers = [];

    Seller::with('user')->get()->each(function ($seller) use (&$sellers) {
        $sellers[$seller->id] = $seller->user->first_name;
    });
?>
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can use Laravel's [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck) method as:

```
$sellers = Seller::with('user')->get()->pluck('user.first_name', 'id')
```

Comment: Calling pluck after get(), is using collection to filter am I right? So we are doing filtering on php side?

Answer (score 19):

try with below solution it's working for me as i am using laravel 8

```php
$sellers = Seller::with('user')->get()->pluck('user.*.first_name')
```

Answer (score 15):

You can achieve it by using [`join()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#joins) & [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck) like this:

```
$s = Seller::join('users', 'sellers.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
          ->pluck('sellers.id', 'users.id')
          ->all();
```

This would give an array like this:

```
[
    'seller_id_1' => 'user_id_1',
    'seller_id_2' => 'user_id_2',
    'seller_id_3' => 'user_id_3',
    'seller_id_4' => 'user_id_4',
    'seller_id_n' => 'user_id_n',
];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You have the arguments backwards in your call to `pluck()`. To get the results that you're suggesting you'd have to call: `pluck('users.id', 'sellers.id')`. The first arg is the value to pluck, the second arg is the value to use as the array key per plucked value.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is to define what columns you need inside the relationship. It's good if you always need just these columns on the given relationship. Example:

```
Class Seller extends Model {
    ...

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(user::class, 'id')
            ->select('id', 'first_name');
    }
}
```