# Pluck Eager Loading Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How would I pluck an eager loading content while querying with Laravel 5.4?

I tried this way:

```
$something = Something::with(array('something_else' => function($query){
    $query->pluck('field');
}))->first();
```

And `$query->select('field')` too, but without luck. Is this possible in Laravel 5.4?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635146/laravel-pluck-fields-from-relations

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the query log so you can see how eloquent actually builds these queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to use `pluck` on the query but you can use `select` if you want to limit the fields returned with eager loading.

You just need to make sure you include the `id` so that Eloquent can match the relationships correctly e.g.:

```
$something = Something::with(array('something_else' => function($query){
    $query->select('id', 'field');
}))->first();
```

---

With Laravel >= 5.5, you can specify the columns you want included  by appending `:` followed by a comma separated list of the fields. This means the above can be simplified to:

```
$something = Something::with('something_else:id,field')->first();
```

Please note that the related column fields need to be included for this to work i.e. the `id` for "belongs" relationships or `*_id` for "has" relationships (and `*_type` if polymorphic).

Comment: I exactly want to hide the id. There is someway to workaround this? I have an entity with two fields: the id and the data. I want to serialize the data into an array like `['data1', 'data2', etc.]`