# How to access a json file via PHP

Tags: php, json, laravel, web

I have this Json file what I want to do is access all the "name" attributes.Is there any way to access that attribute.And I want to do this with PHP (laravel). since this json got dynamic name I can't figure out a away to access this.

```
[
[
    {
        "2": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Asiri Medical Hospital - Kirula Road - Colombo 05",
            "specializations": [
                {
                    "id": 58,
                    "name": "Endocrinologist"
                },
                {
                    "id": 122,
                    "name": "Diabetologist"
                }
            ]
        },
        "3": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Asiri Central Hospital - Norris Canal Road-Colombo 10",
            "specializations": [
                {
                    "id": 58,
                    "name": "Endocrinologist"
                },
                {
                    "id": 122,
                    "name": "Diabetologist"
                }
            ]
        },
        "11": {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "Ninewells Care Mother and Baby Hospital (Pvt) Ltd",
            "specializations": [
                {
                    "id": 58,
                    "name": "Endocrinologist"
                }
            ]
  }
]
```

]

Comment: Question is marked as duplicate, but with WRONG question specified in duplicate. Actual duplicate is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635146/laravel-pluck-fields-from-relations

Answer (score -1):

The easy way is with [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). And then [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the result of `file_get_contents`.

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($path_to_file))
```

Then you can use al different array functions to get what you want.

Comment: That is not an answer to the question OP is asking.