# Pluck the values from WITH Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, with-statement, pluck

I have a dropdown box that shows only the user with collector and borrower's role. Here's my code

```
public function create()
{
    $users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
                $q->where('roles.name', '=', 'collector')->orWhere('roles.name', '=', 'borrower');
            })
            ->with('profile')
            ->get()
            ->pluck('name','id');

    return view('dashboard.documents.create', compact('users'));
}
```

this code is fine but what I what to pluck is the column first_name, last_name and user_id from 'profile'.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel pluck fields from relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635146/laravel-pluck-fields-from-relations)

Comment: `pluck('profile.first_name');`

Comment: I think you need [only](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-only) instead of pluck

Comment: thanks @miken32! Also I'm wondering is possible to add the last name inside the pluck? because what I need to show in the select field is the first_name and last_name

Comment: `pluck()` is for pulling a single column out of the results. You may be looking for `get()` instead, or `only()` as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

You do one of these

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
             $q->where('roles.name', '=', 'collector')->orWhere('roles.name', '=', 'borrower');})
            ->with('profile')
            ->select('name','id')
            ->get();
```

Or

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
             $q->where('roles.name', '=', 'collector')->orWhere('roles.name', '=', 'borrower');})
            ->with('profile')
            ->get(['name','id']);
```

Both ways will return a `collection` with related models each model record will has the selected columns, if you want to convert it to an array you can add `->toArray()` after the two ways and it will convert the collection to array.

Comment: hi do you know how will I be able to use profile.first_name and profile.lastn_ame as a selection in the Select field instead of "name" from user table?

Comment: You can access it like `profile.first_name` and `profile.last_name`